# Show each n-th column, hide others in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I have several big tables, and I know that each 4th column is interesting for me, i.e B,F,J,N, etc (The total number of columns is different in different documents)

Is there an easy way (some sort of a script) I can use to hide all other columns in few clicks?

Comment: how about filter out every 4th column into a separate sheet with one cell formula?

Comment: I guess that could work if nothing else, but it's less desirable since being able to occasionally unhide would be nice

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

- for columns **A**, **D**, **H**, **L**, etc.

  ```
  ={Sheet1!A1:A, FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Sheet1!A:A), 
   COLUMNS(Sheet1!1:1), 4)), NOT(MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!1:1), 4)))}
  ```
- for columns **D**, **H**, **L**, etc.

  ```
  =FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Sheet1!A:A), 
   COLUMNS(Sheet1!1:1), 4)), NOT(MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!1:1), 4)))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It creates a menu, then you have the option to hide and to show the columns.
In the hiding function, it asks you which is the first column you want to hide, and how many columns.
Tell me if it works!

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.createMenu("Columns")
    .addItem("Hide Columns","hideColumns")
    .addItem("Show Columns","showColumns")
  .addToUi()
}

function hideColumns() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var column = sh.getLastColumn() //this is the number of the last column with Data
  Logger.log(column)
  var col = Number(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Which is the first column you want to hide?").getResponseText()) // Here it will ask which is the first column you want to hide. 2 for B, 3 for C, and etc.
  var amount = Number(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("How many columns do you want to hide?").getResponseText()) //You'll be able to determine how many columns you need to hide, but if you want just to establish it as every 4th column, change this with "var amount = 3"
  //Logger.log(col)
  while (col <= column-amount){ //while the given number remains smaller than the total columns...
    sh.hideColumns(col,amount) //... it will hide from the column given by you "col" all the columns you've determined (amount)...
    col = col+amount+1 // ... then it will determine a new column to hide by adding the amount of hidden columns +1...
  } //... and the loop will repeat while "col" is smaller to "column"
  if(col<column){ // it is the last step to hide the last columns when the amount of columns is inferior to the remaining columns
    sh.hideColumns(col,column-col+1)
  }  

}

function showColumns() { //this just unhide every column in the range
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var column = sh.getLastColumn()
  sh.showColumns(1,column)
}
```

Comment: Martin, the question is from 3.5 years ago, so the OP is unlikely to try your solution, nor give you feedback.  Since other people may find the post looking for help, you can improve it by explaining the steps to implent your solution which is not clear.

Comment: I realised later it was "bumped" by a bot. I didn't know about that dynamic earlier. I'll try to explain it in the code, thanks